# How to quit the JShell and go back to the command-line?

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

When using the JShell, how do I exit it back to the CMD line?

I have already tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> and just writing quit, but to no joy.

Comment: Type `/help` to get all commands. You're looking for the `/exit` command. You can also hit Ctrl+D which signals "end of file" which also causes it to exit.

Comment: `vim` comes to my mind...

Comment: I tried everything short of just banging the keyboard like a chimpanzee, thanks for the question/answer

Comment: before killing your keyboard or computer, its most often worth checking the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jshell.html) ... Not to mention the message when starting: "*For an introduction type: /help intro*"

Answer (score 184, accepted):

You can use the [JShell command](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jshell.htm#JSWOR-GUID-C337353B-074A-431C-993F-60C226163F00) to exit as:

```
/exit
```

You can also type the end-of-file character, which is Ctrl-D on Linux systems.

***Side note***: Interestingly, with the use of command abbreviations for input shortcuts:-

```
/ex
```

(of course `/exi`) also, resolves into the same command.

[image]

To see a list of JShell commands like this one, use the `/help` command.

Comment: `/help` will show the 'commands' available from the JShell -- It's good to mention here, as on the Original Question.

Comment: @JosiahYoder feel free to edit and propose the change as this answer is owned by the community itself :)

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctlr</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will quit the JShell and go back to the command-line.

Answer (score 3):

inorder to exit from jshell you can use the command /exit